# Getting multiple button captions into an edit field with one fuction

Tags: c++builder

I want to create a function which takes the `Caption` of a pressed button and put it into an Edit field. I have multiple buttons, and I don't want to have multiple `OnClick` events with almost the same code in each of them.

I've searched and tried out stuff for hours, but can't seem to find anything like that (but I think I am not the only one with this problem).

I am not really new to programming but neither am I good at it.

Edit: I remember that there is a parameter in the click functions in .NET which is `EventArgs e`, which is missing while working with Embarcadero.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    edit.Text = e.Caption; //I don't really remember the exact syntax but I hope you get what I meant
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code you've tried and explain why it isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most VCL/FMX event handlers have a `Sender` parameter, which is a pointer to the object that is firing the event.  For example:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    Edit1->Text = static_cast<TButton*>(Sender)->Caption;
}
```

Just assign this single event handler to the `OnClick` event of all of your `TButton` objects.  The `Sender` will be the current button being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Note to the above answer by Remy - for VCL the property name is "Caption" but for FMX the property name for a button is "Text"